# How to implement a breadcrumb component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

NOTE: I am not using Vue-Router.

I want a simple breadcrumb to track which page/component the user is on, whilst I have implemented it and it works fine, it does not feel very clean. Would be good to get some ideas, and maybe make this into a small lib...

In my breadcrumb single file component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vk-breadcrumb>
                <vk-breadcrumb-item v-show="currentView === 'Modal' || 'Purposes' || 'Vendors'" v-on:click="$emit('change-view', 'Modal')" href="#">Home</vk-breadcrumb-item>
                <vk-breadcrumb-item v-show="currentView !== 'Modal'" v-on:click="$emit('change-view', 'Purposes')" href="#">Purposes</vk-breadcrumb-item>
                <vk-breadcrumb-item v-show="currentView === 'Vendors'" v-on:click="$emit('change-view', 'Vendors')" href="#">Partners</vk-breadcrumb-item>
        </vk-breadcrumb>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['currentView'],
}
</script>
```

And then I simply pass the view as a prop from the parent/root:

```
<app-breadcrumb v-bind:current-view="currentView" v-on:change-view="updateView"></app-breadcrumb>
```

Would be nice for this to be more dynamic :)

Comment: The problem with your implementation is that it feels very hard-coded from a representational viewpoint. That is, you wouldn't be able to reuse this component elsewhere, or update any components you compose it with, without modifying the component itself. You might consider structuring this component such that it takes an array of objects, with each object describing the views that allow and/or disallow displaying of the breadcrumb as well as the click event value you want to emit. Think of it as passing a config object to the component and then rendering according to the configuration.

Comment: Thank you, will take a crack at that! Since no downvotes - safe to assume this is an ok Q for SO?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain if this falls under acceptable questions here. It's not explicitly supported, but also not explicitly considered off topic. That being said, good questions here typically have objective answers to them, and what your question is asking is rather subjective in nature. With that last point, it may be considered a non-ideal question for SO. With all that being said, I chose to answer your question regardless and chose to focus on the more objective aspect of your component having minimal reusability, and did so here in a comment.

Comment: In the future, however, please consider taking a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for any questions regarding code quality. They're far more geared toward the open-ended discussions of code structure and best practices and are more dedicated to questions like this one :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!